# Unable to install PHP

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, php

I can't install PHP on my raspberry pi. I did  sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt and then showed me this:

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php
E: Unable to locate package php-mcrypt
```

On my sources.list I got this:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: It should be `apache2-mod-php5`. But you should really upgrade from Jessie to Stretch and install php7. `php-crypt` is deprecated and removed from php7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `sudo apt update` first and see how it goes and if possible post the `ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org` result for the RPI3 on paste.debian.net and give us the link. There is no package exactly named `php` but the php package available is as `php7.0`. So you are supposed to run `sudo apt install php7.0` instead of `sudo apt install php` and you can always search for a package (apt will intelligently show relevant or closely related package names if the exact match is not found) by `apt search package_name`

Comment: thanls mate, really helped, i have another question but i dont know why i cant post it.  can i ask you here by a comment? only if you are agree with it. (its about my GPIO, its giving me 1.2 v not 3.3v )

Comment: @FreddyAlexSaavedra not a pro on that, sorry and you supposed to be able to ask new questions as you have asked already.

Answer (score 3):

i used

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 -y
```

it works ok for me

Comment: RIP `php5` ....